# Create combobox with non selectable separator

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flash-builder

I'd like to custom combobox.
Indeed, I like to create a combox with two array separate by a line like that.

[image]

The line between All and above 40 must no selectable.

Do you know how to do that?

Thanks for helping

Comment: You may be able to do this with a custom renderer that displays a horizontal bar above the renderer under certain situations.  But that may be confusing regarding selection and hovers and the sort.  With a SparkList, you may add the "Separator" as an item in the dataPRovider; and use an itemRenderer function to display the horizontal line; but making the bar non selectable may require extension.  IF neither of those are "Good enough" For you.  You're going to have to Extend the ComboBox and possibly the List in order to achieve this functionality. It sounds like fun

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I think it may suffice to set the separator itemRenderer's `enabled` property to `false`

Comment: @RIAstar It may... will that make the renderer not selectable?  If so; that is probably exactly what he's looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we have a ComboBox with a model like this:

```
<s:ComboBox>
    <s:ArrayList>
        <fx:String>A</fx:String>
        <fx:Object />
        <fx:String>B</fx:String>
    </s:ArrayList>
</s:ComboBox>
```

The Strings are our regular elements and the Object represents the separator. I'm simplifying things here, but you should be able to translate this to your specific situation.

Now we want to assign a different ItemRenderer to each type of element. We can do this by means of the `itemRendererFunction` property.

```
<s:ComboBox itemRendererFunction="getItemRenderer">

private function getItemRenderer(item:*):IFactory {
    var renderer:Class = item is String ? DefaultItemRenderer : SeparatorItemRenderer
    return new ClassFactory(renderer);
}
```

Now lets create that `SeparatorItemRenderer` which will contain just a horizontal line and will have its `enabled` property set to `false`. This last part is very important because it will make the item non-selectable.

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                autoDrawBackground="false" enabled="false"
                height="10" disabledAlpha="1">

    <s:Line left="0" right="0" verticalCenter="0">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="0xdddddd" />
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Line>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

And that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

With your help, I found a solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="{(data.separator==0)?true:false}"
                disabledAlpha="1"
                enabled="{(data.separator==0)?true:false}"
                mouseEnabled="{(data.separator==0)?true:false}"
                >

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.components.supportClasses.ListBase;

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal"/>
        <s:State name="down"/>
        <s:State name="hovered"/>
        <s:State name="selected"/>
        <s:State name="dragging"/>
        <s:State name="normalAndShowCaret"/>
        <s:State name="hoveredAndShowCaret"/>
        <s:State name="selectedAndShowCaret"/>
    </s:states>




    <s:Group top="2" left="2" right="2" bottom="2" width="100%" height="100%" >
        <s:Line width="100%" bottom="2" visible="{(data.separator==1)?true:false}" verticalCenter="0" >
            <s:stroke>
                <s:SolidColorStroke weight="2" caps="round"/>
            </s:stroke>
        </s:Line>

        <s:Label id="labelDisplay" verticalCenter="1" horizontalCenter="0" fontWeight="normal" color="#000000"
                 visible="{(data.separator==0)?true:false}" />
    </s:Group>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: This may work; however I **STRONGLY** Recommend not using a single itemRenderer to do both the horizontal line and the actual data.  Use an itemRendererFunction as @RIAstar recommended.

Comment: OK, I follow your advice and @RIAStar recommendation. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works in Flash without Flex in case anyone needs that (like I did). First create a new class file for a custom extension of CellRenderer:

```
package { 
    import fl.controls.listClasses.CellRenderer; 
    public class MyCustomCellRenderer extends CellRenderer
    {
        // override the data setter to set the enabled flag
        override public function set data(value:Object):void
        {
            super.data = value;    
            this.enabled = !(value['disabled']);
        }
    } 
}
```

Save it as MyCustomCellRenderer.as (or whatever you call it), then when you set up your ComboBox:

```
myComboBox.dropdown.setStyle("cellRenderer", MyCustomCellRenderer); 
myComboBox.dataProvider = new DataProvider();
myComboBox.dataProvider.addItem({label: "Normal Item"});
myComboBox.dataProvider.addItem({label: "Separator", disabled:true});
```