# Adding horizontal separator and Auto-Complete feature in Flex Combo-box

Tags: apache-flex, photoshop

I am developing a Panel in Flex. The Panel has a combo-box which displays the system fonts. I have created an array collection and filled it with available system fonts and set this array collection as data provider of the combobox. I want to do the following but is not able to do so:

1. **Adding non-clickable horizontal seperator in the combo-box-**
   I wanted to display a horizontal separator in the dropdown list of the combo-box at some particular locations. But I found examples to add horizontal separator in popup button control.
2. **Auto complete feature in the combo-box-**
   I want to implement the auto-complete feature of the combo-box as done in "font-family" combo-box of Character Panel in Photoshop.

Can someone please provide me some sample code or guidance to achieve the above.

Comment: Those are two completely different questions. Number 1 is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728530/create-combobox-with-non-selectable-separator/10729051 (which I've [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728530/create-combobox-with-non-selectable-separator/10729051#10729051)).

Comment: Hi RIAstar, Thanks for the reply. I came across your post and even tried your solution. I am developing the Panel for Photoshop but using the given solution I was not able to display the spark components in Photoshop. I mean that panel is displayed empty in Photoshop. I am using Flex 4.5 builder.

Comment: I'm not familiar with using Flex components in Photoshop, but I don't see why it would behave differently. What happens when you run the component outside of Photoshop?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to implement the auto-complete feature of the combo-box

Well, I'm biased, but I strongly recommend you check out our [AutoComplete component](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductHome&productID=19).  We have an MX Version, a Spark version, and a mobile version.  It is also available for free for development / production use.

Aside from that; [Hillel Coren's](http://hillelcoren.com/flex-autocomplete/) AutoComplete is held in high regards by many developers.

[Every other Flex AutoComplete component I've come across appears to be half baked]